# SQL Server 2012 Support on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server

Is it possible to install **Microsoft SQL Server 2012** on **Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter**?

On the **Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter** - I have .Net Framework 3.5.1 Features(.Net Framework 3.5.1) and I even manually installed .Net Framework 4.

> The operating system on this computer does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL Server 2012. For Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008 operating systems, Service pack 2 or later is required. For windows 7 or windows server 2008 R2, Service pack 1 or later is required. For more information, see Hardware and software requirements for installing SQL Server 2012 at: 
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=195092

I tried to install Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 & 2?

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste error messages, rather than post a screen shot of your whole screen. That avoids unnecessary image downloads for every reader, and also makes the error message searchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can install SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2 (the matrix [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx) - which is exactly where the link in your screenshot goes, if you had clicked it - shows the supported edition/OS combinations).

The error message you posted tells you exactly what you need to do without even going to that page: Apply [Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842) to the operating system.

(Though - especially if setting up a new system - you should consider a more modern operating system, and a newer SQL Server version for that matter.)

Comment: If I am right then something like this - Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1?

Comment: @kerpekri You should apply the latest service pack available for your operating system. (You should be doing this even if software like SQL Server doesn't require it.)

Comment: Thanks for help Aaron, everything works fine after update.

Comment: is it possible to install Microsoft management studio on Windows Server 2008 r2 datacenter?

Comment: @kerpekri Yes. Did you try it? [The list of supported operating systems is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx).

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work, when I click on installation file it is just not responding. Probably I am missing something here? And I even tried to run installation file as a administrator. Could it be a problem that I am not connected to the internet?

Comment: Sorry, don't know... did you check to see if maybe you have a UAC prompt hiding behind another window? "not responding" usually means it is waiting for input, and the UAC prompts have a sneaky habit of ducking behind other applications. Try disabling UAC altogether.